# Which is the fastest lib to decoding Jpeg in iOS?

Tags: ios, jpeg, decode

I am writing a Image management app.

I want to open a jpeg and its thumbnail as fast as I can. so user can enjoy viewing their images.

Which is the fastest lib to decoding Jpeg in IOS?

I used to use IJL and decode the image just in 1/8 size, it is really fast in PC. Is there any lib in iOS just like IJL？

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile and use libjpeg (http://www.ijg.org/).

To open the thumbnail quickly, set the `scale_num` and `scale_denom` values:

```
jpeg_decompress_struct * cinfo_;
/// .....
cinfo_->scale_num = 1;
cinfo_->scale_denom = 8; // open photo in 1/8 size
```